# Naming a file so it appears at the top when listing files

Tags: linux, command-line, filesystems, file-management

What I want to do is make it so a particular file is listed at the top when using ls or browsing via file manager like Nautilus. I want this to work without any system configuration as the files will be on a number of machines. If this was Windows I would just prefix the file name with an underscore e.g `_myfile.txt`, however this does not seem to work using Linux.

The reason I want to do this is because I want a couple of README files to listed before the others so they will have better viability. I Googled around but couldn't find a definitive answer, does anyone know how I could this, or even if it is possible? Any advice is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: add "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" prefix to a file :)

Comment: I've tended to use underscores for items that need to be listed first. This works in Windows Explorer (which, in newer versions of Windows, is nonetheless smart enough to sort 9 before 10). However, the file managers for most major Linux desktop environments, including Dolphin, Nautilus, and [Thunar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunar) (the Xfce file manager), ignore underscores, so this really won't work in a Linux environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nautilus tries to be clever in sorting filenames, (mostly) ignoring non-alphanumeric characters and sorting numbers "naturally" so that e.g. `9z.txt` appears before `10a.txt`. The result of this "cleverness" is sometimes rather odd.

Because filenames beginning with numbers appear before filenames beginning with letters (and the rather odd way Nautilus sorts filenames that begin with a mixture of digits and non-alphanumeric characters), a filename like `_0_README` will appear before any others. You could extend that with a scheme like:

```
_00_READ_ME_FIRST
_01_NEXT_READ_ME
```

... which should also sort as you intend in the Windows file manager.